# Convert a string structured as a Multidimensional Array to array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have this string:

```
array(array('1','name1','1','0'),array('2','name2','0','1'),array('3','name3','0','1'),array('4','name4','1','1'),array('5','name5','1','0'));
```

Stored in `$_POST['data']`

The string I`m receiving is via`.load` function where the structure of the string is constructed like so.

I would like to convert it to a multidimensional array via php so I can loop through it easily

So far I`ve reached a workaround by modifying both the string and the method.

Now my string looks like this :

```
1,name1,1,0,|2,name2,0,1,|3,name3,0,1,|4,name4,1,1,|5,name5,1,0,|
```

And the method is this

```
$data2 = $_POST['data2']; /// get data


      $data2 = substr_replace($data2 ,"", -2); // eliminate ,|
      $data2 = $data2."|"; // add |


$one=explode("|",$data2);  // create multidimensional array
      $array = array();
      foreach ($one as $item){
          $array[] = explode(",",$item);
      }
```

I can keep this solution but I would like to know if there is another way of doing it as first requested

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: So far I`ve reached a workaround by modifying both the string and the method.

Now my string looks like this : 1,name1,1,0,|2,name2,0,1,|3,name3,0,1,|4,name4,1,1,|5,name5,1,0|

And the method is this 

$data2 = $_POST['data2'];


      $data2 = substr_replace($data2 ,"", -2);
      $data2 = $data2."|";


$one=explode("|",$data2);
      $array = array();
      foreach ($one as $item){
          $array[] = explode(",",$item);
      }

I can keep this solution but I would like to know if there is another way of doing it as first requested

Comment: Please post your above code in Question as it is easier to read there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a better and simple way. You just need to use a `foreach` loop inside `foreach` loop.

```
$data = array(
    array('1','name1','1','0'),
    array('2','name2','0','1'),
    array('3','name3','0','1'),
    array('4','name4','1','1'),
    array('5','name5','1','0')
);

foreach( $data as $d ) {
    foreach( $d as $value ) {
        echo $value;
        echo '<br />';
    }
}
```

You can check the online [Demo](https://3v4l.org/tBrEo)

Answer (score 0):

To parse your original string you can use eval()

```
$string = 'array(array('1','name1','1','0'),array('2','name2','0','1'),array('3','name3','0','1'),array('4','name4','1','1'),array('5','name5','1','0'));';
eval('$array = '.$string);
```

But eval can/should be disabled on the server, because it comes with security issues.

What i would do is to use JSON, where you would POST the json encoding it with:

```
json_ecnode( $my_array );
```

and then decoding it:

```
$array = json_decode( $_POST['data'], true );
```